# Problem With \ When Converting object to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a problem when I convert an object to XML. The result is like

```
<Entry From=\"08:46:07\" To=\"20:47:06\" TypeId=\"1\" />
```

and I want to remove the `\` in the XML. How can I do this?

Comment: You should show some of the code you're using...

Comment: @Dan Dumitru: The code is likely the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845697)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are those slashes actually there?

This is what you would see in the debugger when looking at a string with quotes but without `\`.